# Log4net Order log entries for Multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net

I do have 2 parallel threads that write to the same logFile using the log4net file appender using this pattern:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss} %-5level - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

The problem is once I add an entry log like:

```
_log.Info("Something to log");
```

I will find my log with non ordered entries, from Thread A and B. What I would like to have is:

```
Log File: 
  + Log 1 Thread A
  + Log 2 Thread A
  + Log 3 Thread A
  + Log 1 Thread B
  + Log 2 Thread B
```

... And so on

How can I achieve this? Is there something in Log4Net that can achieve this? I taught first about keeping the logs in memory and then flush it once the thread finished, but it's not a good idea if the process will be killed, all the entries will be lost.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Logging is usually ordered by time stamps. You could create 2 separate log files. Or maybe better: log to a database. You can then apply any filter/grouping/sort order you like.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your response. Currently each thread is a process, and there is a constraint to use one log file. If each thread log to the same file in the same time it would be messy and not readable at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems because you are running 2 processes, you can add a buffer forward appender. The following example shows how to configure the BufferingForwardingAppender to buffer 100 messages before delivering them to the ConsoleAppender.

```
<appender name="BufferingForwardingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender" >
    <bufferSize value="100"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</appender>
```

The messages partially order in blocks of the BufferSize.